# Login Authentication control in CKEditor config file with using ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, ckeditor, ckeditor.net

Hi I am creating a blog for myself with using ASP.NET MVC 5 Framework. And I use CKEditor to create blog posts. Of course unauthenticated people will not create or edit. To create posts, login is needed exactly. I have this code in **config.ascx** file:

```
  public override bool CheckAuthentication()
{   
    if (Session["IsAuthorized"] != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

But I get an error when I try to upload pictures:
**The file browser is disabled for security reasons. Please contact your system administrator and check the CKFinder configuration file**

How can I get rid of this error? Or how can I achieve my purpose? Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with simple authentication. If my account is loged in, Create, Edit and Delete buttons work. Otherwise, does not work. Wants to log in. I added **[Authorize]** to ActionResults of Create, Edit and Delete methods. I am sorry for this silly question :D